# How to create a Select which let's you choose between valid types with single table inheritance in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance

i'm using Single Table Inheritance in ruby on rails to model various animals. So i have a base Animal Class and then i have various subclasses in the models/animal folder.

When the user creates an animal, i want to show a select of the various animal types which allows the user to choose a "valid" animal ( which means one animal for which a class exists ).

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two choices are

- `Animal`[`.subclasses`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Class/subclasses) lists all direct subclasses.
- `Animal`[`.descendants`](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/descendants) returns all subclasses regardless of level.